# \w doesn't work in vim search replace but a-zA-Z does?

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace

## tldr

`[a-zA-Z\.-]` works in Vim regex search replace, but `[\w\.-]` does not.

## The text I'm searching:

```
1 string.here   blah blah
24  another-string.here   blah.
1523    another-string.goes.here.  blah123
```

## Desired output

```
string.here
another-string.here
another-string.goes.here
```

## My Question

Why does this work:

```
:%s/\v^\d+\s+([a-zA-z\.-]+)\s+.*/\1/g
```

But this does not:

```
:%s/\v^\d+\s+([\w\.-]+)\s+.*/\1/g
```

> E486: Pattern not found `:%s/\v^\d+\s+([\w\.-]+)\s+.*/\1/g`

The only difference between the two is `a-zA-Z` vs `\w` inside square brackets. But doesn't `\w` *equal* `a-zA-Z` (plus some other non-whitespace characters not in this example text)?

I'm using default vim. Unmodified. Whatever comes with Ubuntu.

## Non-vim platforms

When I try with the atom text editor instead of vim, both expressions work.

Search: `^\d+\s+([a-zA-z\.-]+)\s+.*`
Replace: `$1`

When I try with [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3op95) both expressions work. (Although I have to add the multiline tag)

## Other things I've tried

My understanding is that `\v` is necessary for avoiding escaping hell. I've tried without it:

```
:%s/^\d\+\s\+\([a-zA-Z\.-]\+\)\s\+.*/\1/g
```

works

```
:%s/^\d\+\s\+\([\w\.-]\+\)\s\+.*/\1/g
```

does not work. ("Pattern not found")

I've also tried adding the `m` flag (so the end is `/gm`) but that didn't work

> E488: Trailing characters

I've also tried without the `^`.

```
:%s/\d\+\s\+\([\w\.-]\+\)\s\+.*/\1/g
```

> E486: Pattern not found: `\d\+\s\+\([\w\.-]\+\)\s\+.*`

I've also tried using `\\w` instead of `\w`.

```
:%s/\d\+\s\+\([\\w\.-]\+\)\s\+.*/\1/g
```

> E486: Pattern not found: `\d\+\s\+\([\\w\.-]\+\)\s\+.*`

I've also tried using `\[ \]` instead of `[ ]`.

```
:%s/\d\+\s\+\(\[\\w\.-\]\+\)\s\+.*/\1/g
```

> E486: Pattern not found: `\d\+\s\+\(\[\\w\.-\]\+\)\s\+.*`

Comment: vim does not support escape characters in character classes

Answer (score 2):

> `[a-zA-Z\.-]` works in Vim regex search replace, but `[\w\.-]` does not.

`[a-zA-Z\.-]` is a collection of *characters* containing:

- every character from `a` to `z`,
- every character from `A` to `Z`,
- the character `.`,
- and the character `-`.

`:help /collection` is regrettably not explicit about this but character classes like `\w` are interpreted as "escaped `w`", and thus "plain `w`", so `[\w\.-]` is really just `[w\.-]` which is not what you want:

- the character `w`,
- the character `.`,
- and the character `-`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. How *can* I do `[\w]`? I already tried `[\\w]`. In this situation I can do `a-zA-Z`, but I'd like to know for situations where typing out the full family is super long (e.g. `\S`)

Comment: Why would you do `[\w]` or `[\S]`? If it worked it would be strictly equivalent to `\w` and `\S` so there would be no benefit.

Comment: As an alternative, see `:help [:alnum:]` and related character class expressions.

Comment: Sorry, when I said `[\w]` I meant a group with `\w` *and other stuff*. (e.g. `[\w\.]`). `[[:alnum:]\.-]` does work. Thanks. However if I need to learn a bespoke set of long magic strings because Vim can't understand canonical regex, I don't see the point of using Vim. I'm just gonna go back to Nano.

Comment: You are free to use any tool you want and you are free to not put any effort into learning it.